# Print matrix from list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I just started to practice with Python and have to print the next list with.

```
list = [{'Name': 'Jorge Luis', 'last_name': 'Arzuaga', 'age': 32,
         'Sex': 'M', 'grades': [1.5, 1.5, 1.5], 'Prom': 1.5},
        {'Name': '2', 'last_name': '2', 'age': 2,
         'Sex': 'F', 'grades': [1.5, 1.5, 1.5], 'Prom': 1.5}]
```

this ist just an example the list is from a program that let the user insert the values of an n number os students and save them in that list.

my problem is the output it has to be something like this

```
 --------------------ESTUDIANTE 1-----------------------------
Name:  Jorge Luis Arzuaga 
age:  32
Sex:  M   
grade 1: 2.0    
grade 2: 2.5    
grade 3: 2.3    
average:  2.3

--------------------ESTUDIANTE 2-----------------------------

Name:  2 2    
age:  2    
Sex:  F    
grade 1: 1.5    
grade 2: 1.5    
grade 3: 1.5    
average:  1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an f-string:

`foo = f"bar"`

Comment: This will do nothing. You need to have curly braces in ```f``` strings, ```f"{bar}"```

Answer (score 0):

Read the `list` into dataframe initially.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(list)
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
print(f'-------------student{idx+1}------------------')
print(f"Name : {row['Name']+' '+row['last_name']}")
print(f"Age : {row['age']}")
print(f"Sex : {row['Sex']}")
print(f"Grade1 : {row['grades'][0]}")
print(f"Grade2 : {row['grades'][1]}")
print(f"Grade3 : {row['grades'][2]}")
print(f"Average : {round(sum(row['grades'])/len(row['grades']),2)}")


Output:

-------------student1------------------
Name : Jorge Luis Arzuaga
Age : 32
Sex : M
Grade1 : 1.5
Grade2 : 1.5
Grade3 : 1.5
Average : 1.5
-------------student2------------------
Name : 2 2
Age : 2
Sex : F
Grade1 : 1.5
Grade2 : 1.5
Grade3 : 1.5
Average : 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the dictionary items:

```
for m,i in enumerate(list2,start=1):
    print(f'------------------Student {m}-------------------')
    for key,val in i.items():
        if isinstance(val,list):
            for i,j in enumerate(val,start=1):
                l_c=val.copy()
                print(f"Grade {i} = {j}")
        else:
            print(key," : ",val)
    print("Average : ",round(sum(l_c)/len(l_c),2))
```